# ui:inputCheckbox and aura:iteration: value binding

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, inputcheckboxes, iteration

I am currently writing a lightning component made of a table of elements that can be selected (or not) using a ui:inputCheckbox.

So the way I do is fetching the data from APEX controller during the `onInit()` method call and store them in a aura:attribute:

`<aura:attribute name="products" type="Object[]" default="[]" />`

Every product is an object with an array of options inside it:

`product: { selected: false, options: [] }`

My component is made of an iteration over the products to store them in a `<table>` but also of an inner iteration product's options.

```html
<aura:iteration items="{!v.products}" var="product">

  <ui:inputCheckbox value="{! product.selected }" 
                    updateOn="change,click" 
                    change="{! c.productSelected }" />

  <aura:iteration items="{!product.options}" var="option">

    <ui:inputCheckbox value="{! option.selected }" 
                      updateOn="change,click" 
                      change="{! c.optionSelected}" />

  </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

My problem is that I have an handler on `option` that should check the parent product when selected and an handler on `product` that should uncheck its options when unchecked.

```js
({
  optionSelected: function(component, event, helper) {},
  productSelected: function(component, event, helper) {
    const products = component.get('v.products');
    // find options or product the way you want
    // product.selected = true;
    // product.options.forEach(option => option.selected = false);
    component.set('v.products', products);
  }
})
```

But doing this way, my `ui:inputCheckbox` are not updated depending on the `selected` attribute even if the `v.products` object is well updated.

Any idea the way I can trigger the UI to refresh depending on those values ?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your browser support ES6? If not, your arrow function might be the problem.

Comment: Yep, I tried with few browser it is support. Anyway, the component are transpiled into an ES5 build by Salesforce using Google Closure Compiler.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_debug_mode.htm

Comment: Can you try using "keyup" attribute on checkboxes? 

<ui:inputCheckbox value="{! product.selected }" 
                    updateOn="change,click" 
                    change="{! c.productSelected }" keyup="change" />

Comment: Is options of a inner class type? Inner class won't work for lightning components

Comment: @LanceShi : Inner Class does not work in Lightning components agreed .. however i have seen instance where <aura:attribute type="ParentClass.Object" name="Single" /> or <aura:attribute type="ParentClass.Object []" name="Collection" /> work .. ideally its substituting the innerClass name with Object ( javascript object ) .. worth giving it a try..

Comment: @Sumuga Interesting point. I will try it out.

Comment: What do you mean by inner class ? In my example, my APEX controller use a custom APEX class to wrap the data returned with SOQL. The class is serialised  as a JS object without any specific type ( `any` in terms of Typescript, so no type).

`fetchProducts.setCallback(this, function (response) {
      const products = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());

      component.set("v.products", products);
    });
  }`

Comment: And an other fact is that I use the binding with `ui:inputNumber` on fields from `product` and `options` without any problem.